# R: Cleaning up a plot's increment labels and background

Tags: r

I'm new to R and this is a homework assignment. I just need to create some simple graphs.

I need to clean up the plot's increment labels (I don't know what else to call them) by adding 0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, and 2500 to each axis. I'd also like to reduce the spacing on the background to intervals of 100. Also, if you know a simpler way to remove all of the legend elements that would be cool. Thanks for the help.

Here is my code. I assume you can just copy and paste on your computer to see the messy result I'm getting.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("lubridate")
library("reshape2")
library("gdata")

# PSRC park and ride data

 parkride <- read.xls("http://www.psrc.org/assets/5748/parkandride-2010.xls", 
                 sheet=2,
                 na.strings="*",
                 skip=1)

plot1 <- ggplot(parkride, 
            aes(x=Capacity, y=Occupancy, color="blue")) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlim=c(0, 2500), ylim=c(0, 2500) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(angle=0)) +
  ggtitle("Puget Sound Park and Ride \nLots Capacity and Occupancy") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", lineheight=1.25)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.text=element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.key=element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.background=element_blank())
```

Comment: I'm getting error that suggests you have not included all the data manipulations. parkride$Capacity, for instance, is a factor, as are most of the other columns.

Comment: Since this *is* homework, the point is for you to learn how to use `ggplot2` .  I easily found two PDFs online with titles like "ggplot-intro.pdf" ; these should be very useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

1. add the `stringsAsFactors=F` when you read in the data. Should usually do this unless you have a reason not to.
2. Check `str(parkride)` and notice that your numbers are coming in as characters. You may need to clean the data because not every value is numeric.
3. Recode the columns that you will graph as numeric
4. Subset to remove the NAs, or manually clean the data.
5. Add the color within the geom_point
6. group theme changes together.
7. use the long form of xlim `scale_x_continous` it wasn't working previously because of factors and characters.

   parkride <- read.xls("http://www.psrc.org/assets/5748/parkandride-2010.xls", 2,
                    skip=1, stringsAsFactors=F)

   parkride$Capacity <- as.numeric(parkride$Capacity)
   parkride$Occupancy <- as.numeric(parkride$Occupancy)

   pr_subset <- subset(parkride, !is.na(Capacity) & !is.na(Occupancy))

   plot1 <- ggplot(pr_subset, aes(Capacity, Occupancy)) + 
   geom_point(colour="blue") +
   scale_x_continuous(c(0, 2500)) + 
   theme(
     legend.title=element_blank(),
     legend.text=element_blank(),
     legend.key=element_blank(),
     legend.background=element_blank()
   ) +
     ggtitle("Puget Sound Park and Ride \nLots Capacity and Occupancy")

   plot1

A lot of this is learned through trial and error. Try going through the tutorials in books like 'R Graphics Cookbook'.